# How to add data to collection in an object Angular 5+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to add data to my collection inside an object from my TypeScript code. I am successfully getting the `name` and `type` from the view in the html binding So I was wondering how I can edit the `this.newList.socialData` model via code before adding the new list to my database.

Html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="List Name" [(ngModel)]="newList.name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" required>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="List Type" [(ngModel)]="newList.type" name="type" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" required>
</mat-form-field>
<button (click)="addList()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Create New</button>
```

Declaration:

```
newList: List = {} as List
```

TypeScript:

```
addList() {
    let tt = {} as SocialData;
    //tt.socialId = 'jj'
    //this.newList = {} as List;
    // I would like to add test data to socialData here
    this.newList.socialData.push(tt);

    this.listService.addList(this.newList)
      .subscribe(
            res => {
          this.fetchLists();
        },
        err => console.log(err)

      )
}
```

Model:

```
export class List {
    name: String;
    type: String;
    inputValue: String;
    socialData: [SocialData]
}
export class SocialData {
    socialId: String
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear what you're asking. What is it you want to do? Edit which model? How do you want to edit it?

Comment: My apologies, I would like to know how to add data to  `this.newList.socialData`.

Comment: What issue are you having with `this.newList.socialData.push(tt);`? You may get an error if `socialData` is undefined, so you may need to initialise it to an empty array first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess to just want to add a new item to the socialData array.
You need to make 2 changes in your code:
1. Declaration

```
export class List {
  name: String;
  type: String;
  inputValue: String;
  // socialData: [SocialData]; // This is wrong
  socialData: SocialData[]; // declares a type of array

  constructor() {
    this.socialData = [];  // Initialize the array to empty
  }
}
```

2. Creating the instance:

```
// let tt = {} as SocialData; // This will just cast an empty object into List  
newList: List = new List(); // Will create an instance of List
```

Just make these changes and the code should work.